# FBSDK (New Facebook SDK 4.0) Implementation is not working for Login with Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, sharing

I am using this following block which is mentioned in **Facebook Developer**.  But when my **App** callbacks from **Browser** then it is always returning **Cancelled** result.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]     
        handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
        // Process error
   }
  else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
   }
   else {
       // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
       // should check if specific permissions missing
       if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
        // Do work
       }
  }
 }];
```

> ## this update comes on 25 March 15,

If anyone used this then please share it with me.

Reference :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: did u login from browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You cant get Email id from Facebook Login....why???

#### If your Facebook account registered using "Mobile Number", and you do not have Email in same account.

Check this scenario. This might be happening, We cant blame for it to **FBSDK**.

Hope this will clear some points.

Answer (score 11):

You must add the following method in your appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

If the above method is not present into AppDelegate then it results into cancelled state.

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#startcoding

Comment: Thanks...This helped me....I was not updated this block...now its working....Thanks

Comment: but not able to get **UserProfile**

Comment: I have the delegate method and same block of code for login. I get a url in app and then it just stops working. I don't receive any callback.

Comment: That was it! Argh, Facebook's documentation is just awful!

Answer (score 7):

You use this simple block with your expected requirements

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
      [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id user, NSError *error)
       {
           if (!error)
           {
            //  NSDictionary *dictUser = (NSDictionary *)user;
            // This dictionary contain user Information which is possible to get from Facebook account.
           }
        }];
}
```

## Access Token you will get only and only after successfully login

### Hope this will help you

Answer (score 4):

To get user profile try this

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
                {
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id user, NSError *error)
                     {
                         if (!error) {
                             NSDictionary *dictUser = (NSDictionary *)user;
                             self.txfName.text      = [dictUser objectForKeyNotNull:@"name"];
                             self.txfEmail.text     = [dictUser objectForKeyNotNull:@"email"];
                             self.txfUserName.text  = [[dictUser objectForKey:@"first_name"] lowercaseString];
                             NSLog(@"image : https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=small",[dictUser objectForKeyNotNull:@"id"]);
                         }
                     }];
                }
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: Thanks a lot,, helped in in getting the user details, +1 for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following line caused isCancelled to always be true... idk why

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"gender"]
```

After changing to this... it worked

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
```