# Social sharing on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, sharing, social-framework

I am working on an app that capable of share images through Facebook, Twitter, Instagram. I have integrated Facebook login for the app by using Facebook iOS SDK. What is the best approach to enable social sharing,

1. Use three SDKs for iOS,

or

2. Use Apple social media framework integration

Comment: The Social Framework allows you to share via Facebook and Twitter. For Instagram you'll need to use an `UIActivity​View​Controller`. Really depends on how much control and how many options you'd like. If all you want to do is share something then I'd suggest the Social Framework.

Comment: You can get your answer for sharing with **FACEBOOK** on this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363490/fbsdk-new-facebook-sdk-4-0-implementation-is-not-working-for-login-with-facebo

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use ShareKit [(link to GitHub)](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) which allows to work with a lot of services to share content.

Answer (score 1):

For sharing images on your facebook wall you can use **apple social media framework** i.e. **SLComposeViewController class**

While sharing on your friend's wall use SDK provided by Facebook developers

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

For facebook and twitter sharing you can use Social framework.But for the **instagram** sharing you have to use **UIActivityViewController**.

Follow the link for facebook and twitter sharing:

[how to share content on facebook, twitter and instagram using SLComposeViewController swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263309/how-to-share-content-on-facebook-twitter-and-instagram-using-slcomposeviewcontr/49192393#49192393)

**100% working and easy steps**