# Unable to get the access token through FBSDKLoginKit when I am try to login in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook sdk to share text on facebook but unable to get access token when try to login. login is done successfully but did not get any access token. 
So without access token I am unable to share the text on facebook.
My code are as follows

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {


if ([result.token hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
      initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
      parameters: @{ @"message" : @"hello world"}
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Post id:%@", result[@"id"]);
         }
     }];
}

if (error) {
    // Process error
} else if (result.isCancelled) {

    // Handle cancellations
} else {
    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
    // should check if specific permissions missing
    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

}];

i get the result in handler block of FBSDKLoginManager object without error but it does not contain the token or other data

output is as follow

[image]

please tell me how to resolve this problem
Thanks

Comment: Looking at the result object, it was cancelled for some reason. This post suggests that the login wasn't successful because your app is not handling the login callback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29366524/78496

Answer (score 4):

Try This code. Based on Facebook SDK version 4.0

**AppDalegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut];
             }
         }
     }];
}

-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }

}
```