# Its possible to get Facebook friends list in app with latest SDK in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to get friends list from Facebook to my app.Its possible in new SDK.thank you..

Comment: yes new SDK provides friend list but those friend who can use your app. @priya

Comment: refer this link @priya http://stackoverflow.com/a/30253688/4536708

Comment: yes possible, you have to give permission of read_custom_friendlists, and after call graph method, you got object close friend and others.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/friendlist

Comment: You can't get all your fb friends, you can get only the app users those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to everyone.my working answer is here

```
      FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
     [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]   handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
         {
     if (error)
     {
         // Process error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Handle cancellations
     }
     else
     {
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
             NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                      if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
                   {
                 NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                      }
                  }];

             }
             //[login logOut];
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: I am unable to get the friends list but it showing only friends count like this. friends =     {
        data =         (
        );
        summary =         {
            "total_count" = 243;
        };
    };

Answer (score 3):

With Facebook SDK 4.0 onwards, you will get your total facebook friends count and the list of facebook friends who are using the same app. Facebook has restricted this usage, you can use "user_friends" permission to retrieve the list but can have only those friends who are using app created by you. So, no full list access to anyone from now.

Answer (score 2):

Swift version:

```
var fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: nil);
fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        println("Friends are : \(result)")

    } else {

        println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

    }
}
```

Note: this only gets you the friends who also use the same app!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You need to use `Facebook SDK` and it's `graph API`. You can take a look here:

[Getting started - Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

Here is an example of code in Objective-C:

```
// For more complex open graph stories, use `FBSDKShareAPI`
// with `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent`
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{friendlist-id}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```